# `Implementation-Version` not in Manifest after `spring-boot-maven-plugin` repackage

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, manifest.mf, fatjar

Given this plugin config in a Maven `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>acme.Main</mainClass>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Why would `MANIFEST.MF` be missing `Implementation-Version` and `Implementation-Title`, given that all docs that I can get my hands on, either don't mention it, or imply its creation is a default?

The complete generated Manifest is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.8.6
Built-By: stewart
Build-Jdk: 17.0.5
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: acme.Main
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.7.5
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Spring-Boot-Classpath-Index: BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
Spring-Boot-Layers-Index: BOOT-INF/layers.idx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, behind the scenes, `spring-boot-maven-plugin` still relies on the Manifest created by `maven-jar-plugin`, because that's the base `.jar` that is being repackaged.

Having established that, we then find that

> [Starting with version 2.1, Maven Archiver no longer creates the
> Implementation and Specification details in the manifest by default.
> If you want them in your manifest you have to say so explicitly in
> your configuration.](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html)

Thus, what is needed is to add the following to the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```